# CCLOG - why is cocos2d-x cclog doesn't work on iphone device?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am new to cocos2dx. when using CCLOG, My iphone device did not show log, however **simulator can**. I already checked the COCOS2D_DEBUG macro, and my app is in debug mode, so i really don't know what's happening, pls help me out.

Comment: You should show samples of code of what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CCLog instead of CCLOG.